# Dependency Injection Winforms MVP or MVC with Unity vs2010

Tags: winforms, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am looking for some samples or how you build a winform app using MVP/MVC using Unity.

Where I work they use Unity,so in my project I have to use Unity too.

I am faced with the usual questions about DI but this is not asp.net mvc where there are many many samples but Winforms.

My questions are:

1. Using a pattern like MVP or MVC how do you inject multiple services into a presenter or controller? I want to avoid a constructor with 10 services for instance.
2. If you have Form1 that calls form2 that calls form3 how do you build this in a compositionRoot?
3. Any small samples somewhere?

   4.If I dont inject 10 services then how do I mock that Service.Is there something like a serviceFacade/Container that holds the 10 services?

How do you go about it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Using DI (or any tech) just because they want you to instead of having a clear reason for it is almost always bad. As far as your question, other than framework specific stuff like the mvc bootstrapper, Unity works pretty much the same in any kind of project. If your company is already using it you should have some examples.

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for your answer.I do have a clear reason I want to use Unity,is because to make the system more loosely coupled.In the company they use it but only in web app not winforms.It's as simple with winforms as most of the stuff is web and it's not the same

Comment: Well as I said Unity works the same in any type of project. I can see using it for libraries but not forms.